# System.Net.FtpClient - changing access right to file

Tags: c#, ftp

I have problem with Net.FtpClient.

How to change rights to file on the server. I use the Execute but I get error: **CHMOD not understood**

```
if (!(reply = conn.Execute("chmod 666 file.txt")).Success)
{
throw new FtpCommandException(reply);
}
```

Package from: https://netftp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does the user that you are using have permission to write the file?

Comment: Yes, the file was uploaded by me.

Comment: what is the type of your `conn` variable?

Comment: conn is the FtpClient: FtpClient conn = new FtpClient(), changing name working, create files, create folder working but change right's not working.

Comment: is your Server running under Windows system?

Comment: no, server runing under linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution

```
if (!(reply = conn.Execute("SITE CHMOD 666 file.txt")).Success) {
   throw new FtpCommandException(reply);
}
```

refer [here](https://netftp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Examples/Execute.cs) for documentation

if this doesn' work check if Server is running under Windows system. If yes it does not allow to set file permissions via FTP (UNIX-running servers allow that).

If your hosting provider has a web-based control panel that allows you to set file permissions go there and make your changes.

Comment: @LucasWork happy to help you. don't forget to mark one answer as accepted to avoid that the question remains unanswered.